ideal of $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ containing polynomials can be represented as finite intersection of maximal ideals
I got the motivation from the question at here.

Prove that any ideal of $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $I$ is a subset of ideal generated by  polynomials $f_1,\dots, f_n$ ( given the variety is finite) can be represented as finite intersection of maximal ideals.

My progress/proof:
Let the maximal ideals be $m_1,\dots, m_k$.
Let $I$ be any ideal which contains $f_1,\dots ,f_k$. Then $I$ is contained in finitely many maximal ideals (positive), say $m_{a_i},\dots, m_{a_l}$ ( they are all the maximal ideal containing $I$). If $m_{a_i}\cap \dots \cap m_{a_l}=J\ne I$.
Since $J\ne I, I\subset \implies \exists$ polynomial $p$ such that $p\in I\implies p$ has a root ($\alpha$) which is not in the variety of $I$. But then we know maximal ideals and roots correspond with each other. So $\exists a_g$ such that $M_{a_g}=M_{\alpha}$.
But that is not possible as $I\not\subset M_{\alpha}$.
I am not sure if my second part is correct.

For an ideal to be such an intersection, you at the very least need it to be a radical ideal.

@Mark can you point out what is wrong in my progress?

@psl2Z but I assumed the variety is finite

I don't really understand what you did in the last paragraph. Did you claim that $I$ equals the ideal of polynomials that vanish on all the points of the variety of $I$? If so, that's not true. This ideal is $\sqrt{I}$.

Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ be an radical ideal. Then $I = m_1\cap \dots \cap m_l$ for maximal ideals $m_i$ if and only if $V(I)$ is finite.
If $(f_1,\dots,f_n) \subseteq I$ and $V(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ is finite then $V(I) \subseteq V(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ is finite and therefore $\sqrt{I} = m_1\cap\dots\cap m_l$ for some maximal ideals $m_i$.

How do you get the last statement? Like how do you guarantee that $\sqrt I$ is intersection of some finite maximal ideals?

@Raheel $\sqrt{I} = I(V(I)) = I({p_1,\dots,p_l}) = \bigcap_{i=1}^l I({p_i}) = \bigcap_{i=1}^l m_i$ by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz and  $I(p_i) = m_i$ where $V(I) = {p_1,\dots,p_l}$.
